# Using Chrome DevTools timeline to measure: Function Call, Recalculate Style, Layout and Paint time

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building real time time layout.

If server sends packages every 200ms, then Function Call + Recalculate Style + Layout + Paint time must be less than 200ms.

[image]

By using `performance.mark` with `performance.measure` or just `console.time('1')` with `console.timeEnd('1')` i can measure `Function Call` what is not enough.

Is there any known way how to put some sort of anchors to get and log number that includes Paint?

That will be used for automated performance testing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to log Paint times using the [Console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference). It looks as though there was an attempt to integrate this into [WebKit several years ago](https://trac.webkit.org/raw-attachment/wiki/QtWebKit/CodeCamp200912/Performance%20JS%20APIs.pdf), but this never got implemented. Right now, you can only do CPU profiling using `console.profile`, but this isn't relevant for you.

You need to explicitly run the Timeline tool to gather Paint profiling data. You could look into using macros to run this. You can export your data into a JSON file, so that you can re-import and compare each one. It's not optimal for automated testing, but I'm not sure of other ways.

[image: Save Timeline Data]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to include the paint time itself, but [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) will be called just before the paint.

I also tried `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, but it turned out to be called fairly long after the paint.

If all you want to know is that there is some time left at the end of a frame you might be able to use [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback?hl=en).